# Adding multiple alias in crypto.properties in WS security

Tags: java, security, cryptography, cxf, wss4j

How do I add multiple alias in crypto.properties file in Apache WSS4J configuration

${PREFIX}.merlin.keystore.alias :   The default keystore alias to use, if none is specified.
that's all I got from the documentation http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html .
Now how do I specify an alias in the same crypto.properties file. I have several certificate in my keystore and I want to specify them in my crypto.properties file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to specify more than one alias in the crypto.properties file. To be more clear, this alias refers to the private key used to encrypt messages sent by the application (or decrypt them), not the certificates/public keys trusted by the application, and it's normal to have only one private key per application.

The only case that could explain your need is if your application have one certificate + private key per environment, I think. 
In that case, you can have one crypto.properties file per environment, with only one alias specified in each of them, and the same keystore for all environments, or one crypto.properties with a common alias for all environments, and one keystore per environment.

I hope my explanation is understandable. Please, don't hesitate to ask me for clarifications if you need or if I misunderstood your intentions ^^.

Have a good day.

---

**Edit**

The crypto.properties file concerns only our service, and only our service. It's used to set the certificate and the associated private key needed to encrypt and/or sign messages it sends.

In order to authenticate the clients signatures, you have to configure a truststore at server-side.

Maybe the CXF samples projects can help you to configure our own service : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html. I don't know if you use CXF or another framework, but I think the approach should be very similar.

I can't be more precise if I don't know which authentication protocol you use in your implementation.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm trying to do exactly the thing that you mentioned in the post above, i.e trying to store certificates my application is suppose to trust. But my application is such that it has two clients having their own respective certificates which uses the same services provided by my application, and I need to authenticate/encrypt/decrypt them on the fly, depending on where the request came from. Maybe my approach is wrong but I would very much appreciate if I could be pushed to the right direction since I'm still new to this WS security. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I completed my answer. I think you need a concrete example and I hope you'll find that in the CXF samples. If you can provide me more information about the authentication protocol you want, maybe I could help you more ^^.

Comment: **Hi Kevin** thank you and yes I am using CXF WS Security, sorry I failed to mention that earlier. I need only to verify the signature from the clients which I'm doing with a WSS4J interceptor. I have two keys in a keystore, one for each client respectively. When a request comes from any client, I want to be able to verify the requests by checking the keystore and dynamically selecting a certificate to use to verify based on the origin of the requests. The problem is that the aliases for a particular certificate is hardcoded in the crypto.properties file.

Comment: The reason I wanted to add multiple aliases was maybe we can iterate through the certificates to see if it can be verified with any certificate in my keystore. I guess my approach is not correct, I'll look into that truststore, it sounds like that's what the i'm looking for.

Comment: You don't need to iterate through the certificates at all. A certificate is found in a truststore with the Common Name (CN), in this case (just as HTTPS). For example, if you have a signature + encryption protocol, if a client send a message to your service, he provides a signature in the header and an encrypted body. Your service will look for our client certificate, check the signature (i.e automatically decrypted with a trusted certificate, found by the CN in the truststore), and decrypt the message (with the private key referenced into the keystore and crypto.properties file).